# Git doesn't pickup chmod change from 0775 to 0774

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, git

Git is ignoring a chmod change from 0775 to 0774. I want to deny public execution of a certain file.

```
0775:
Owner: Read, Write, Execute
Group: Read, Write, Execute
Public: Read, Execute

0774:
Owner: Read, Write, Execute
Group: Read, Write, Execute
Public: Read
```

I have `git config core.fileMode` set to `true`. If I run `chmod 0644 foo.sh`, Git sees the file mode change and allows me to commit that.

However, if I my file has permissions 0755 and I run `chmod 0774 foo.sh`, Git doesn't show it up as modified and doesn't allow me to commit that.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git only [looks at modes 644 and 755](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620335/what-is-gits-filemode#19621116). And it possibly doesn't even look at flags that don't apply to you.